# sending collection with object into another List

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oop

I have static method which returns me as it's name says data from domain model.

```
public static List<PropertyViewModel> FromDomainModel(List<Property> x)
{
   List<PropertyViewModel> dataVm = new List<PropertyViewModel>();

   foreach (Property p in x)
   {
       dataVm.Add(new PropertyViewModel(p));
   }
   return dataVm;
}
```

**Bellow is viewmodel which above FromDomainModel calls**
....other properties ...

```
public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
```

and first contructor

```
public PropertyViewModel(Property x)
{
    Id = x.Id;
    ...
    List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();
    foreach (var item in x.Photos)
    {
       Photos.Add(item);
    }
}
```

On debug mode I'm having collection of Photos until it reaches the line in FromDomainModel() method

```
 List<PropertyViewModel> dataVm = new List<PropertyViewModel>();
```

on debug in line `dataVm.Add(new PropertyViewModel(p));` p actually holds properly collection.
Question is why is not passed inside list dataVm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're hiding the property Photos by declaring a local variable with the same name on this line:

```
List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();
```

By using the type name `List<Photo>` before the name `Photos`, you are declaring a new variable that is hiding the Property.

You can fix this by using the actual property:

```
Photos = new List<Photo>();
```

or, to be even more specific:

```
this.Photos = new List<Photo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the PropertyViewModel constructor you're populating a local list of Photo objects, then as you leave the constructor that collection will be lost. It looks like you instead want a Photo collection against the PropertyViewModel class populated

i.e. rather than:

```
 List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();
```

you shouldn't have a local(to the constructor) Photos collection but instead just use a property of PropertyViewModel:

```
public class PropertyViewModel  
{  
  public List<Photo> Photos { get; private set; }  

  public PropertyViewModel()  
  {  
    ...  
    Photos = new List<Photo>();  
    ...  
  }  
}
```